Display the status of the GCB trigger journal on Github PR using a different reference branch defined in the trigger
I'm wondering if there's a way to display the status of a trigger on a different PR than the one in the reference branch of a Google Cloud Build (GCB).
My goal is to trigger a webhook when a label is added to a pull request to build an APK. I'm using a GitHub action to detect get the event label added and then call my GCB webhook with curl.
The problem I'm facing is that the webhook always triggers on my default branch, rather than the branch where the label is added.i have no problem creating my apk, I just need to do a checkout with the branch name I give as substitution.
However, the trigger's status isn't being displayed on my PR because the reference branch is the project default branch.
Do you have any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.
